# How to achieve consistent line breaks between browsers using web fonts

Tags: html, css, text, fonts, line-breaks

I am trying to get fonts to render equally across browsers in an application where line breaks must be consistent. Content is user-generated.

Bold makes the letters wider. With the default browser font, the line will then break earlier when text is wrapped in a container.

When using web fonts, the line does not lengthen when bold is applied in Chrome, but it does in Explorer. This leads to inconsistent line breaks across browsers.

**UPDATE:**
Firefox behaves same as explorer (web-font text lengthens when bold applied). Non-web fonts in chrome behave same as in other browsers. Apparently, chrome  (version 47) has an abnormality with the rendering of web fonts, since this is the only case that behaves differently. I opened a [bug report](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?can=2&q=bold%20web%20fonts&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified&id=578533&thanks=578533&ts=1453018278) that links to this question.

[Simplified test case](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WrEpQL)

**HTML**

```
<h2>will break in chrome and explorer:</h2>
<div>
hover to make the text bold and break the line!

</div>

<h2>will break in explorer only:</h2>
<div class="web-font">
hover to make the text bold and break the line!

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
@font-face { font-family: 'roboto'; src: local('roboto'), url(https://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/roboto/v9/2UX7WLTfW3W8TclTUvlFyQ.woff) format('woff'); 

}

div{
  width:380px;
  height:100px;
  border:5px solid gray;
  font-size:20px;
  margin-bottom:10px;
}

.web-font{
    font-family: 'roboto';
  font-size:18px;
}

div:hover{
  font-weight:bold;
}
```

I tested both .ttf and .woff formats with equal results.

I tried tweaking CSS properties such as letter and word spacing but of course results will vary depending on the text so this is not a viable solution for variable content.

Comment: Have you tried in your CSS: word-break: keep-all or word-wrap: normal?

Comment: word-break: keep-all and/or word-wrap: normal  have no effect in the test case.

Comment: Could you create a jsfiddle or jsbin? Will be a lot easier to try and fix it with that :)

Comment: I can't think of any CSS property that would do this automatically. The fact is that character glyphs are different widths in different typefaces / fonts...even monospaced ones, I can't think of an instance where this would actually be required (other than poetry perhaps)  but perhaps you could clarify the use case.

Comment: @Chirs G: the 'simplified test case' link in the question points to a code pen example.

Comment: Pauline_D the use case is presentation software with text being positioned in relation to shapes and images on a slide. Each text 'element' is being wrapped in a div, and lines break according to the width of the div. When a user creates a presentation in chrome, they expect it to be visually identical in explorer.  In chome, applying bold to a web font does not increase the text length. in explorer, it does. This causes the lines to break differently in explorer and causes misalignment of text in relation to other elements on the slide.

Comment: to clarify, the fact that character glyphs are different widths in different typefaces is not an issue. The issue is inconsistent effect of font-weight:bold on web fonts across browsers.

Comment: @CodeToad Did you manage to find a decent workaround? Or is this something we have to live with?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a work around?

```
div:hover{
  text-shadow:0 0 1px Black;
}
```

instead of:

```
div:hover{
  font-weight:bold;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MKOgYw

Comment: Very clever and creative workaround :)  Its got the trade-off of heavier painting and rendering cost, and it will change existing content in production, so I am not sure if I can use this, but certainly a clever approach to the problem :)